# Until vs as long as

Tags: conjunctions

I’ve read that until means:

> up to the point in time or the event mentioned

Now the question is, which of the following is correct, while I mean to say that **‘You must leave so that things can be good here.’**

```
1. Things will not be good until you are here.

2. Things will not be good as long as you are here.
```

I feel the second one is correct. The first sentence seems to mean: *****to make things good you should come here. i.e. that person is not here.*****

Comment: (1) means "Things are bad here, you are not here, you must come here so that they will be good". (2) means "Things are bad here, you are here, you must leave so that they will be good here".

Comment: It means if I say, "Our institution cannot progress until we become professionals." is correct. And I can't use 'as long as' in this sentence, right?

Comment: _Cannot do X until_ means that the conditions making X possible do not yet exist. _Cannot do X as long as_ means that X is impossible in current conditions.

Comment: You are correct on both counts.

Answer (score 2):

Your two examples are total opposites.

- "As long as [x]" means that the condition will be met when [x] **ends**.
- "Until [x]" means that the condition will be met when [x] **begins**.

So, to mean "*to make things good you should come here. i.e. that person is not here*" you would say either:

1. Things will not be good until you are here.
2. Things will not be good as long as you are **not** here.

If it were the opposite (that the person's presence makes things bad), you could say:

1. Things will not be good as long as you are here.
2. Things will not be good until you leave.

Answer (score 0):

In your original examples

> 1. Things will not be good until you are here.

> 2. Things will not be good as long as you are here.

2. expresses your intent.

In your further queries in the comments

> Our institution cannot progress until we become professionals.

To use 'as long as', you can consider the following:

'Our institution cannot progress as long as we have not become professionals.'